# Is there a proper way of performing this task without resorting to custom built subroutines?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

### Question summary

I wrote an excel macro in VBA that imports a large text file, reads each individual line to determine number of data to store, allocates the correct size for an array to hold the data, and then opens the file a second time to write the data into the array.

The problem I encountered with this program was the large text file has inconsistent tab sizes line for line. I had to write a special delimit filter function to select the correct data to store into the array.

Is there a proper way of performing this task without resorting to custom built subroutines?

### Program specs

The program must perform data analysis for best fit with the following model `$y_k = c_1 x_k + c_0 + c_{-1}(x_{k})^{-1}$`, which includes a negative exponent. The program cannot allow the data to be left in the Excel spreadsheet after exit, however that does not mean it cannot be placed their temporarily. Performance and speed are important for the impatient user. The data imported can have unspecified number of repeating column types and undefined tab length delimits.

### Open to suggestions

I am open to the idea of exploiting predefined excel functions and storing the data in excel variables temporally.

### Determine size of data from text file

```
Dim LineText As String ' indiviudal line of row text from data file
Dim runs As Long ' number of delimited column of data we're interested in
Dim count As Long ' number rows in data file
Dim data() As Double 'data from text file
Dim i As Long ' array index
iF1 = FreeFile ' Returns an Integer representing the next file number available for use by the Open statement.
Open MyFile For Input As #iF1 'open data file first time
Line Input #iF1, LineText ' skip first line
Line Input #iF1, LineText ' read second line
runs = Len(LineText) - Len(Replace(LineText, "T", "")) ' number of occurences of character T
count = 0
While Not EOF(iF1) 'EOF means 'end of file'
    Line Input #iF1, LineText
    count = count + 1
Wend ' end of while loop
Close #iF1 'close text file
ReDim data(count, 2) 'resize 'data' array to number of rows in text file
```

### reopen text file and store all data to array

```
Open MyFile For Input As #iF1 ' reopen data file second time
    Line Input #iF1, LineText ' skip first line
    Line Input #iF1, LineText ' skip second line
    i = 1 'set index to first element in array
    While Not EOF(iF1) 'EOF means 'end of file'
        Line Input #iF1, LineText 'read line from text
        data(i, 1) = Val(delimit_extract(LineText, 4 * runs - 0)) ' frequnecy data
        data(i, 2) = Val(delimit_extract(LineText, 4 * runs - 2)) ' voltage data
        i = i + 1 'update array index
    Wend ' end of while loop
    Close #iF1 'close text file
```

### delimit_extract function

```
Private Function delimit_extract(text As String, x As Long) As String
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''function finds xth number in string text regardless of tab size
''x is the xth number desired in text
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim c As String ' holds indiviudal characters from text
    Dim i_start As Long 'stores first index of recently discovered number
    Dim i_end As Long 'stores last index of recently discovered number
    Dim x_count As Long 'tallies current count of numbers discovered in text
    Dim flag As Boolean ' flags true if first index of new number false otherwise
    i_start = 1
    i_end = 1
    x_count = 0
    flag = True 'set flag true for possible discovery of new number
    For i = 1 To Len(text) ' loop through all characters in text
        c = Mid(text, i, 1) 'extract individual character from text
        If (c = ".") Or (c = "-") Or (c = "E") Or ((Asc(0) <= Asc(c)) And (Asc(c) <= Asc(9))) Then 'if character is related to a number
            If flag = True Then 'catch new number discovered
                x_count = x_count + 1 '' update total number of numbers discovered
                i_start = i ' mark location of number in string
                flag = False ' set recently discovered  number to false
            End If
            i_end = i 'mark last known index of recently discovered number
        Else
            flag = True 'set flag true for possible discovery of new number
            If (x_count = x) Then 'if total discovered numbers equals desired number
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    delimit_extract = Mid(text, i_start, i_end - i_start + 1)
End Function
```

### sample of data text file

```
Run #1  Run #1  Run #1  Run #1  Run #1  Run #2  Run #2  Run #2  Run #2  Run #2
Time (s)    Voltage (V) Output Frequency (Hz)   Calc3 (units)   w   Time (s)    Voltage (V) Output Frequency (Hz)   Calc3 (units)   w
0.000   -0.060  69.940  0.00    0.00    0.000   0.034   29.980  0.00    0.00
5.000E-5    -0.024      1.26E-6 0.05    5.000E-5    0.078       1.26E-6 0.05
1.000E-4    0.059       2.51E-6 0.10    1.000E-4    -0.045      2.51E-6 0.10
1.500E-4    0.008       3.77E-6 0.15    1.500E-4    -0.056      3.77E-6 0.15
2.000E-4    -0.051      5.03E-6 0.20    2.000E-4    0.055       5.03E-6 0.20
2.500E-4    0.008       6.28E-6 0.25    2.500E-4    0.039       6.28E-6 0.25
3.000E-4    0.047       7.54E-6 0.30    3.000E-4    -0.056      7.54E-6 0.30
3.500E-4    -0.013      8.80E-6 0.35    3.500E-4    -0.021      8.80E-6 0.35
4.000E-4    -0.035      1.01E-5 0.40    4.000E-4    0.055       1.01E-5 0.40
4.500E-4    0.023       1.13E-5 0.45    4.500E-4    0.007       1.13E-5 0.45
5.000E-4    0.028       1.26E-5 0.50    5.000E-4    -0.049      1.26E-5 0.50
5.500E-4    -0.024      1.38E-5 0.55    5.500E-4    0.007       1.38E-5 0.55
6.000E-4    -0.017      1.51E-5 0.60    6.000E-4    0.043       1.51E-5 0.60
6.500E-4    0.027       1.63E-5 0.65    6.500E-4    -0.013      1.63E-5 0.65
7.000E-4    0.011       1.76E-5 0.70    7.000E-4    -0.033      1.76E-5 0.70
7.500E-4    -0.026      1.88E-5 0.75    7.500E-4    0.022       1.88E-5 0.75
8.000E-4    -4.272E-4       2.01E-5 0.80    8.000E-4    0.027       2.01E-5 0.80
8.500E-4    0.026       2.14E-5 0.85    8.500E-4    -0.022      2.14E-5 0.85
9.000E-4    -0.001      2.26E-5 0.90    9.000E-4    -0.016      2.26E-5 0.90
9.500E-4    -0.019      2.39E-5 0.95    9.500E-4    0.026       2.39E-5 0.95
0.001   0.009       2.51E-5 1.00    0.001   0.009       2.51E-5 1.00
0.001   0.017       2.64E-5 1.05    0.001   -0.022      2.64E-5 1.05
0.001   -0.010      2.76E-5 1.10    0.001   -0.002      2.76E-5 1.10
0.001   -0.011      2.89E-5 1.15    0.001   0.023       2.89E-5 1.15
0.001   0.013       3.02E-5 1.20    0.001   -0.002      3.02E-5 1.20
0.001   0.010       3.14E-5 1.25    0.001   -0.017      3.14E-5 1.25
0.001   -0.011      3.27E-5 1.30    0.001   0.007       3.27E-5 1.30
0.001   -0.002      3.39E-5 1.35    0.001   0.017       3.39E-5 1.35
0.001   0.013       3.52E-5 1.40    0.001   -0.008      3.52E-5 1.40
0.001   0.003       3.64E-5 1.45    0.001   -0.010      3.64E-5 1.45
0.002   -0.009      3.77E-5 1.50    0.002   0.012       3.77E-5 1.50
0.002   0.004       3.90E-5 1.55    0.002   0.010       3.90E-5 1.55
0.002   0.012       4.02E-5 1.60    0.002   -0.010      4.02E-5 1.60
0.002   -0.001      4.15E-5 1.65    0.002   -0.004      4.15E-5 1.65
0.002   -0.008      4.27E-5 1.70    0.002   0.012       4.27E-5 1.70
0.002   0.005       4.40E-5 1.75    0.002   0.004       4.40E-5 1.75
0.002   0.007       4.52E-5 1.80    0.002   -0.010      4.52E-5 1.80
0.002   -0.004      4.65E-5 1.85    0.002   0.003       4.65E-5 1.85
0.002   -0.001      4.78E-5 1.90    0.002   0.010       4.78E-5 1.90
0.002   0.005       4.90E-5 1.95    0.002   -0.002      4.90E-5 1.95
0.002   0.004       5.03E-5 2.00    0.002   -0.005      5.03E-5 2.00
0.002   -0.005      5.15E-5 2.05    0.002   0.006       5.15E-5 2.05
0.002   -9.155E-4       5.28E-5 2.10    0.002   0.006       5.28E-5 2.10
0.002   0.005       5.40E-5 2.15    0.002   -0.003      5.40E-5 2.15
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to replace (and the replacement text), and your current code?

Comment: It will help if you can provide a small sample of the imported data showing the inconsistent tab sizes, like @Jane mentioned, and your delimiter function that parses the lines as you need. This will allow us to determine some patterns and if we can apply the logic in your function in some other way (without the custom subroutine)

Comment: @Jane code is available

Comment: @paulbica code is avaiabla

Comment: Why don't you just read the txt file into Excel using Get External Data? you can specify the delimitiers as tab and space: works OK on your sample data. Then read the data from Excel straight into an array.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams The data is very large, and writing the data to be displayed in excel is unnecessary. However, its possible if I write at the top of my program to not update the excel sheet, but temporarily store it in specific excel memory, than maybe that would make sense. The end goal of the program is to only write 40 numbers to the excel spreadsheet, and not display all of the data. The 40 numbers are calculated from all of the data loaded into that array.

Comment: Yes, but you can delete the imported data after you have read it: its only temporary. Just seems unnecessary to re-invent in VBA what is already built-in to Excel unless you have more than 1 million rows of data. BTW your first line of data has 10 items but all the rest have 8?

Comment: @CharlesWilliams I know, its not my data, its come from another program which unfortunately I have no control over. I have the location of the temporary file which stores the numbers (possibly in hex), but I cannot open it using notepad. I will investigate storing the data in excel memory. Can I use excel's power series regression with excel data in VBA? The model we use is $y_k=c_1x_k+c_0+c_{-1}(x_k)^{-1}$. The model contains a reciprocal power.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams cpearson writes: "Data transfer between worksheet cells and VBA variables is an expensive operation that should be kept to a minimum. You can considerably increase the performance of your Excel application by passing arrays of data to the worksheet, and vice versa, in a single operation rather than one cell at a time. If you need to do extensive calculations on data in VBA, you should transfer all the values from the worksheet to an array, do the calculations on the array, and then, possibly, write the array back to the worksheet."

Comment: @CharlesWilliams cpearson continues to write: " This keeps the number of times data is transferred between the worksheet and VBA to a minimum. It is far more efficient to transfer one array of 100 values to the worksheet than to transfer 100 items at a time.""

Comment: I'm trying to summarize your task to a minimum: you are importing data delimited by an inconsistent number of spaces, and the end result should be a proper Tab delimited text file, is this correct?

Comment: @paulbica More or less. The data does not have to be reformatted. The data needs to be processed through number crunching to output a number from the data. Hence either storing in an array or excel struct is fine. I have no need to put the data back into a properly delimited text file.

Comment: @paulbica Oh, I forgot to mention, the data cannot be in the excel spreadsheet when the script is finished.

Comment: @linuxfreebird: of course: Are we agreeing with each other?  that is why I suggested loading the txt file into an excel sheet then grabbing all of the data from the sheet into a variant array for processing before writing back the subset from a subset variant array. See https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/getting-cell-data-with-vba-and-c-benchmarking-excel-2013/

Comment: Hard to tell from the sample data - is line 3 part of the headers?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```
Function extractNumbers(line As String) As Variant
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    Dim c As New Collection
    v = Split(line)
    For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        If Len(v(i)) > 0 And IsNumeric(v(i)) Then c.Add v(i)
    Next i
    n = c.Count
    If n = 0 Then Exit Function
    v = Empty
    ReDim v(0 To n - 1)
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        v(i) = CDbl(c.Item(i + 1))
    Next i
    extractNumbers = v
End Function

Sub test(line As String)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim v As Variant
    v = extractNumbers(line)
    If Not IsEmpty(v) Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(v)
            s = s & " " & v(i)
        Next i
        Debug.Print Trim(s)
    Else
        Debug.Print "No numbers found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Typical output:

```
test "Run #1  Run #1  Run #1  Run #1  Run #1  Run #2  Run #2  Run #2  Run #2  Run #2"
No numbers found
test "5.000E-5    -0.024      1.26E-6 0.05    5.000E-5    0.078       1.26E-6 0.05"
0.00005 -0.024 0.00000126 0.05 0.00005 0.078 0.00000126 0.05
test "5.000E-5    -0.024   bob   1.26E-6 0.05    5.000E-5    0.078       1.26E-6 0.05"
0.00005 -0.024 0.00000126 0.05 0.00005 0.078 0.00000126 0.05
```

Comment: How does your code identify the numbers from everything else not a number?

Comment: @linuxfreebird My code assumed that the lines in question consisted of numbers and spaces since that was what your posted example looked like. I modified the code and added an IsNumeric() check.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this?

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SpecesToTabs()

    Const MAX_SPACES    As Long = 10
    Const FILE_NAME     As String = "C:\test.txt"

    Dim fso As Object, txt As Object, dat As String, i As Long

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set txt = fso.OpenTextFile(FILE_NAME)           'open file for reading

    dat = txt.ReadAll                               'read entire file

    If Len(dat) > 0 Then
        For i = MAX_SPACES To 2 Step -1
            dat = Replace(dat, Space(i), vbTab)     'replace space sets with tabs
        Next

        Set txt = fso.OpenTextFile(FILE_NAME, 2)    'open file for writing
        txt.Write dat                               'write back to text file"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

This is what the structure of the tab delimited file will be:

[image]

.

You could get access to (and process) each element of data using Split

```
dat = Split(dat, vbCrLf)    'generates an array of lines

dat = Split(dat, vbTab)     'generates an array of data items for each line
```